# scaling of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I have the following result. Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ containing the origin.

Let $f: X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a differentiable **concave** function. Then for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $c\geq 1$ such that $cx\in X$, we have $f(cx)\leq cf(x)$.

To prove the statement, first note that

$0\leq f(0) \leq f(x) - \langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle \Rightarrow \langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle \leq f(x) $

Now

$f(cx)\leq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), (c-1)x\rangle. \leq f(x) + (c-1)f(x) = cf(x)$

Now suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a differentiable **convex** function. Does there exists a similar relation between $f(cx) $ and $f(x)$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot think of any example of a concave non-negative function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$. My intuition tells me that such a thing does not exist..

Comment: @GReyes, I have changed the statement of the question.

Comment: I see. But then  the expression $f(cx)$ may not make sense for $c>1$ if, say, your domain is a ball and $x$ is on the boundary.

Comment: I think you need a conic domain.

Comment: @GReyes , In case when $f$ is convex, it is defined on the entire $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to have a general relation between $f(cx)$ and $cf(x)$, it would have to be
$$
f(cx)\ge cf(x)
$$
since this is true about $f(x)=\|x\|^2$:
$$
f(cx)=\|cx\|^2=c^2\|x\|^2=c^2f(x)\ge cf(x),
$$
since $c\ge 1$.

Now consider the shifted version (in two dimensions, for simplicity)
$$
g(x_1,x_2)=\|(x_1-1,x_2-1)\|^2
$$
Take the point $x=(1-\sqrt{2}/2, 1-\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $c=(2+\sqrt{2})/(2-\sqrt{2})>1$. Then you can easily check that
$$
g(x)=1, g(cx)=1
$$
and, therefore, $g(cx)<cg(x)$.

Conclusion: there is no such general property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The motivation of my question is depicted here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48203/a-variant-of-randomized-co-ordinate-descent. For the specific convex function defined there I am able to find a $(2+\epsilon)$-approximation in sublinear time. Is there any way to get a $(1+\epsilon)$ approximation from there? That is why I am trying to figure out if nearby point can be used. The $2+\epsilon$ factor comes from my inability to derive some relaxed triangle inequality.